# Google App Engine low level api - saving a custom object as Blob?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a custom object that I would like to save in the datastore(not the blobstore). 
Something like

```
Entity.setProperty("myobj", custonObject)
```

I have a list of users within this customObject

```
public user class{
 String name;
 String age;
}

public user_s class{

 List<user> userList;

 public user_s(){
  userList = new ArrayList<user>();
 }
}
```

I would then like to save user_s.

I guess I need some serialization, if at all possible. I can see that there is a Blob class in the datastore, but how do you use it?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

Regards

Comment: Are you sure, you're talking about Java?

Comment: I agree with Moritz, Please ask your question in a better way, you are asking about Blob Class and sharing the code for saving the List Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a [`Blob`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Blob) class.

Serialization is simple:

```java
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    Blob blob = new Blob(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Though I dont understand why you ask "Are you sure, you're talking about Java?"

Comment: @user699215 The code you're writing in this question is not Java syntax. In Java, you write `public class <class_name>`, where `<class_name>` is typically starting with a capital letter and does not contain underscores.

Comment: What you mean is Hungarian notation

Answer (score 1):

I know your question specifically says "low level API" but you might want to consider using Objectify if you want to avoid having to make boilerplate serialization code everywhere.  Then you can simply use a `@Serialized` annotation on the list of custom objects you want to store.

I would call Objectify "middle-low level"--it gives you a high degree of control in that you can manipulate the Datastore exactly as you wish, without the abstraction/obstruction of JDO, but still lets you avoid a bunch of boilerplate.